# Reducing slug size of Rails App for Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a Rails app running on Heroku and on every deploy I get a warning:

```
Warning: Your slug size (368 MB) exceeds our soft limit (300 MB) which may affect boot time.
```

I want to get under 300 MB. So I ran `du -sh .[^.]* * | sort -hr` which returned:

```
2,1G    .git
176M    node_modules
 79M    vendor
 25M    tmp
5,4M    app
5,1M    public
1,2M    db
420K    test
168K    config
132K    log
116K    package-lock.json
 32K    bin
 12K    lib
 12K    Gemfile.lock
8,0K    dump.rdb
8,0K    .DS_Store
4,0K    package.json
4,0K    config.ru
4,0K    Rakefile
4,0K    README.md
4,0K    Procfile
4,0K    Gemfile
4,0K    .gitignore
  0B    storage
```

tmp/* and log/* are in my .gitignore and removed from git.

The others, if I sum them up don't equal 368 MB. Where are those MB coming from?

I know that there are ways to reduce the node_modules etc. but first I would like to solve the issue above.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that before you added the .slugignore file you had some large files added to the git repo and now they are in the slug cache or as git refs.

**You can remove the cache using the heroku-repo plugin**

#### Install the plugin using the command

```sh
heroku plugins:install heroku-repo
```

#### gc

```
heroku repo:gc -a appname
```

This will run a `git gc --aggressive` against the applications repo. This is done inside a run process on the application.

#### purge-cache

```
heroku repo:purge_cache -a appname
```

This will delete the contents of the build cache stored in the repository. This is done inside a run process on the application.

After following these steps you may push your code to the Heroku.

If it does not work then maybe your `requirements` files are large in size such that it crosses the slug size limit.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Heroku may have updated clearing the build cache - from their docs https://help.heroku.com/18PI5RSY/how-do-i-clear-the-build-cache

Clear The Build Cache
You can clear the build cache for an app by using the Heroku Builds plugin:

First install the plugin:

heroku plugins:install heroku-builds
Then use the following command to clear the cache:

heroku builds:cache:purge -a example-app
The cache will be rebuilt on the next deploy. If you do not have any new code to deploy, you can push an empty commit.

$ git commit --allow-empty -m "Purge cache"
$ git push heroku master
Where appname is replaced by the name of the app you want to clear the cache for.